# Create single .proto file to create message for pub/sub

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

We are using protocol buffers (version 3) for our microservices communications.

We now want to start ingesting those messages into our data storage via sending messages to Google's Pub/Sub.

As best as I can figure out, Pub/Sub requires a proto file with:

- only one message defined
- that message fully encapsulated in the schema that is passed

This is a problem, since we have already created *many* complex protobuf objects and `.proto` files, and we never followed those two rules in the protobuf definitions.

---

Let me explain by the following example of our problem:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package ourprotobuf.order.v1;

import "buf/validate/validate.proto";
import "ourprotobuf/common/amount/v1/amount.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.us.ourprotobuf.order.v1";

message Order {
  optional string id = 1;
  optional string merchant_order_reference = 2 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
  TaxesAndFees taxes_and_fees = 4 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
}

message TaxesAndFees {
  repeated Section sections = 1;
}

message Section {
  // NOTE: not required since it can be empty
  repeated SectionRow rows = 2;
  SectionTotalRow total_row = 3 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
}

message SectionRow {
  optional string title = 1 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
  common.amount.v1.Amount amount = 2 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
  optional string amount_descriptor = 3;
}

message SectionTotalRow {
  optional string title = 1 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
  common.amount.v1.Amount amount = 2 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
}
```

The example `.proto` file is perfectly acceptable when working purely with protocol buffers as generated into the target languages. (We use a different target language for the data reporting team vs the application team, without any problems.)

But as far as I can determine, this is a problem when using Google's Pub/Sub because:

1. The file above pulls in definitions from other files.

   - Eg, it is referencing `"ourprotobuf/common/amount/v1/amount.proto"`, which is a shared protobuf message being referenced.
2. The file has several messages -- `Order`, `TaxesAndFees`, etc. -- that are defined in a "hierarchical" format, but not all within other messages. It is clear to us, as humans, that `Order` is the "main" message that I would like for Pub/Sub to recognize, but I do not know how to make that clear to Pub/Sub. I want for Pub/Sub to know that, for instance, it should never be expecting a message of type `SectionRow` directly, but that `SectionRow` is a sub-message of `Order`.

---

So far, we are using [this package](https://github.com/alpancs/protoc-gen-pubsub-schema) to try to assist us in generating a proper schema for Pub/Sub. But it doesn't seem to be able to fully generate a *single message* that *incorporates internal modules in the package*, as far as I can manage.

---

But I feel like I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be, because:

- I am able to work with the proper protobuf objects in the languages that we're using. Eg, I can create an `Order` object in Python that is completely correct, by importing the generated `order_pb2.py` file.
- I feel there must a way to simply *export* a fully complete `.proto` file message from an object?  In other words, isn't there something similar to:

```py
> my_obj = order_pb2.Order()
> my_obj.exportSchema('./order.proto')
```

where the generated file `order.proto` would have the full schema of the object in a single message?  In other words, the `exportSchema` method would do the reverse of what `protoc` does.

It seems this *must* be possible. The full structure of the object is known from the Python object.

Comment: Drive-by: I was unaware that pub/sub permitted schema validation until reading your question. It should be possible to *expand* well-defined (e.g. hierarchical, using imports) protobuf definitions into a single message but `protoc` doesn't support this. You don't explain why `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema` doesn't work. Evidently, Google built a limited solution and, given Google's lack of commitment to a good solution, I wonder whether you should pursue post-processing to use it. What's the downside to not using validation? Your topics may include invalid messages, can you limit their ingestion?

Comment: @DazWilkin , so far, when I am using `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema`, it is _not in fact making a drop-in replacement_.  If I create a schema via that tool and create a Python object with it, and then I create an object from the original protobuf, the two do not match.  There are two differences: (1) `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema` creates an "extra hierarchical layer" (there is a top level object encompassing the original), and (2) it alters the names of the messages, presumably to ensure no name clashes.  At least insofar as I can get the tool to work.

Comment: As far as the post-processing, I'm not sure what you mean.  I want to ensure that Pub/Sub is able to _ingest_ the messages.  The messages are "correct", in that they are what they need to be.  But the messages are created with imports or with multiple messages defined per file, as I showed.  And Pub/Sub cannot support this format.  It is _a lot_ of work to try to recreate these structures manually.  I am just giving a small toy example, it's our entire stack communicating in protobufs.

Comment: "post-processing" your existing protocol buffer sources in order to make them compatible with Pub/Sub's equivalent but different representation of the schema and, per your previous comment, without there being a tool that facilitates this.

Comment: With regards the equivalence of your sources and the `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema`. Because of Google's Pub/Sub schema limitation on a single message type, the only way to represent hierarchical messages will be to nest message definitions. The on-the-wire message does not include schema metadata (packages, message names etc.) and so, a better test would be to serialize a message using your sources and deserialize using the `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema` *equivalent* and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  But I'm not looking for a _test_.  I'm looking for a means to generate the `.proto` file in the very specific format that Pub/Sub needs (but which most other APIs to protocol buffers do not need).  I need this single file with a single top-level message and no imports.

Comment: The purpose of the test is to prove to yourself that `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema` is generating on-the-wire equivalent messages to your protobuf sources. Once you've proven this to yourself, you can use the plugin. And, if the plugin does *not* generate equivalent on-the-wire messages, then it is invalid and you should submit feedback on its repo explaining this.And, you'll be out of luck (short of writing your own plugin) since there's no other tool that programmatically unwraps sources so that they're pub/sub suitable.

Comment: Yes, I understand, @DazWilkin, but I already know that it is not generating an equivalent.  That's the problem. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on-the-wire messages generated by a tweaked (see below) copy of your protobuf sources and the output from `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema` are identical for me using Go and a tweaked version of your `Order` message.

Since the on-the-wire messages are identical, the schema, are equivalent.

There **is** (at least) one issue: `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema` does not support `optional` fields (these were only recently added) to `proto3`.

###### You may wish to raise this issue on the GitHub rep.

Once this change has been made and after suitable testing, it appears you could use `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema` to programmatically generate schemas suitable for Cloud Pub/Sub from your existing schema.

Proof:

1. `protoc-gen-pub-schema` requires a single top-level message in a protobuf source. This is because it is a plugin for `protoc` and there's no way to specify a single message when compiling protos.

Solution: create e.g. `order.only.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package ourprotobuf.order.v1;

import "buf/validate/validate.proto";
import "ourprotobuf/order/v1/order.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.us.ourprotobuf.order.v1";

option go_package = "{module}/protos";

message Order {
  string id = 1;
  string merchant_order_reference = 2 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
  ourprotobuf.order.v1.TaxesAndFees taxes_and_fees = 4 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
}
```

And revise `order.proto` to exclude `Order`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package ourprotobuf.order.v1;

import "buf/validate/validate.proto";
import "ourprotobuf/common/amount/v1/amount.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.us.ourprotobuf.order.v1";

option go_package = "{module}/protos";

// message Order {
//   optional string id = 1;
//   optional string merchant_order_reference = 2 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
//   TaxesAndFees taxes_and_fees = 4 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
// }

message TaxesAndFees {
  repeated Section sections = 1;
}

message Section {
  // NOTE: not required since it can be empty
  repeated SectionRow rows = 2;
  SectionTotalRow total_row = 3 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
}

message SectionRow {
  optional string title = 1 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
  ourprotobuf.common.amount.v1.Amount amount = 2 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
  optional string amount_descriptor = 3;
}

message SectionTotalRow {
  optional string title = 1 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
  ourprotobuf.common.amount.v1.Amount amount = 2 [(buf.validate.field).required = true];
}
```

> **NOTE** I'm using Go rather than Java and Go requires `option go_package ...`

2. Compile these equivalent sources

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD}/protos \
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go_opt=module=${MODULE} \
${PWD}/protos/ourprotobuf/order/v1/order.only.proto \
${PWD}/protos/ourprotobuf/order/v1/order.proto \
${PWD}/protos/ourprotobuf/common/amount/v1/amount.proto
```

> **NOTE** Absent your definition of `ourprotobuf.common.amount.v1.Amount`, I create a stub `amount.proto`

3. Use the Go sources to generate a sample message:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log/slog"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"

    pb "{module}/protos"
)

func pString(s string) *string {
    return &s
}
func main() {
    order := &pb.Order{
        Id:                     "ID",
        MerchantOrderReference: "MerchantOrderRef",
        TaxesAndFees: &pb.TaxesAndFees{
            Sections: []*pb.Section{
                {
                    Rows: []*pb.SectionRow{{
                        Title: pString("Title"),
                        Amount: &pb.Amount{
                            Title: pString("Title"),
                        },
                    }},
                    TotalRow: &pb.SectionTotalRow{
                        Title: pString("Title"),
                        Amount: &pb.Amount{
                            Title: pString("Title"),
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    slog.Info("order", "order", order)

    b, err := proto.Marshal(order)
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("unable to marshal order",
            "error", err,
        )
    }

    slog.Info("marshaled message",
        "order", fmt.Sprintf("%x", b),
    )
}
```

Yields:

```
2023/12/04 15:19:26 INFO order order="id:\"ID\" merchant_order_reference:\"MerchantOrderRef\" taxes_and_fees:{sections:{rows:{title:\"Title\" amount:{title:\"Title\"}} total_row:{title:\"Title\" amount:{title:\"Title\"}}}}"
2023/12/04 15:19:26 INFO marshaled message order=0a02494412104d65726368616e744f7264657252656622260a2412100a055469746c6512070a055469746c651a100a055469746c6512070a055469746c65
```

The on-the-wire message is `0a02494412104d65726368616e744f7264657252656622260a2412100a055469746c6512070a055469746c651a100a055469746c6512070a055469746c65`

4. Use e.g. [Protobuf Decoder](https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/) with this message.
5. Generate Pub/Sub-equivalent (!) schema using `protoc-gen-pubsub-schema`

```
--proto_path=${PWD}/protos \
--pubsub-schema_out=${PWD}/pubsub \
--pubsub-schema_opt=message-encoding-json \
--pubsub-schema_opt=schema-syntax=proto3 \
${PWD}/protos/ourprotobuf/order/v1/order.only.proto
```

> **NOTE** To avoid naming conflicts, these Go sources are generated to `pubsub` folder (package) rather than `protos`.

6. Compile the Pub/Sub-equivalent schema to Go source:

```bash
# Need to include `option go_package` in generated proto
sed \
--in-place \
--expression="s|package ourprotobuf.order.v1;|package ourprotobuf.order.v1;\n\noption go_package = \"${MODULE}/pubsub\";|g" \
${PWD}/pubsub/ourprotobuf/order/v1/order.only.pps

# Compile pubsub/ourprotobuf/order/v1/order.only.pps
# Generate Go sources in pubsub folder
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD}/pubsub \
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go_opt=module=${MODULE} \
${PWD}/pubsub/ourprotobuf/order/v1/order.only.pps
```

7. Generate message using this schema **and** Unmarshal the message generated using the tweaked original schema into *this* schema

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log/slog"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"

    pb "{module}/pubsub"
)

var (
    // The on-the-wire message generated using the tweaked original schema
    b = []byte("0a02494412104d65726368616e744f7264657252656622260a2412100a055469746c6512070a055469746c651a100a055469746c6512070a055469746c65")
)

func pString(s string) *string {
    return &s
}
func main() {
    order := &pb.Order{
        Id:                     "ID",
        MerchantOrderReference: "MerchantOrderRef",
        TaxesAndFees: &pb.Order_OurprotobufOrderV1TaxesAndFees{
            Sections: []*pb.Order_OurprotobufOrderV1TaxesAndFees_OurprotobufOrderV1Section{
                {
                    Rows: []*pb.Order_OurprotobufOrderV1TaxesAndFees_OurprotobufOrderV1Section_OurprotobufOrderV1SectionRow{{
                        Title: "Title",
                        Amount: &pb.Order_OurprotobufOrderV1TaxesAndFees_OurprotobufOrderV1Section_OurprotobufOrderV1SectionRow_OurprotobufCommonAmountV1Amount{
                            Title: "Title",
                        },
                    }},
                    TotalRow: &pb.Order_OurprotobufOrderV1TaxesAndFees_OurprotobufOrderV1Section_OurprotobufOrderV1SectionTotalRow{
                        Title: "Title",
                        Amount: &pb.Order_OurprotobufOrderV1TaxesAndFees_OurprotobufOrderV1Section_OurprotobufOrderV1SectionTotalRow_OurprotobufCommonAmountV1Amount{
                            Title: "Title",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    slog.Info("order", "order", order)

    b, err := proto.Marshal(order)
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("unable to marshal order",
            "error", err,
        )
    }

    slog.Info("marshaled message",
        "order", fmt.Sprintf("%x", b),
    )

    psOrder := &pb.Order{}
    if err := proto.Unmarshal(b, psOrder); err != nil {
        slog.Error("unable to unmarshal order into Pub/Sub message",
            "error", err,
        )
    }

    slog.Info("Pub/Sub order", "order", psOrder)

}
```

Yields:

```
2023/12/04 15:26:09 INFO order order="id:\"ID\" merchant_order_reference:\"MerchantOrderRef\" taxes_and_fees:{sections:{rows:{title:\"Title\" amount:{title:\"Title\"}} total_row:{title:\"Title\" amount:{title:\"Title\"}}}}"
2023/12/04 15:26:09 INFO marshaled message order=0a02494412104d65726368616e744f7264657252656622260a2412100a055469746c6512070a055469746c651a100a055469746c6512070a055469746c65
2023/12/04 15:26:09 INFO Pub/Sub order order="id:\"ID\" merchant_order_reference:\"MerchantOrderRef\" taxes_and_fees:{sections:{rows:{title:\"Title\" amount:{title:\"Title\"}} total_row:{title:\"Title\" amount:{title:\"Title\"}}}}"
```

> **NOTE** This code works; the Pub/Sub-compatible schema is able to unmarshal the message generated by the tweaked original schema; (redundantly but for completeness) the Pub/Sub-compatible schema is also able to generate the same on-the-wire message

Comment: Thank you for the awesome details!  Let me go through this and see.  I had tried multiple times, but maybe I'd missed a step.  I really appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: You're welcome. I've submitted issues (https://github.com/alpancs/protoc-gen-pubsub-schema/issues/18, https://github.com/alpancs/protoc-gen-pubsub-schema/issues/19) with PRs for permitting use of `optional` with `proto3` and adding a parameter to specify one (of many) top-level messages

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't even get around to doing so yet!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your use case, you wanted to merge all those messages into one full schema, so you can export them as a whole, then you may find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76821473/google-cloud-pub-sub-schemas-too-many-protobuf-messages-in-single-schema#:%7E:text=1-,Answer,-Sorted%20by%3A) from [Kamal Aboul-Hosn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121288/kamal-aboul-hosn) useful.

> A topic can only only have a single schema associated with it, so you cannot separate these into multiple schemas and use them all in the same topic. You could consider defining a single schema that has a union of the types you wish to use:
>
> ```
> message FullSchema {
>   message M1 {
>     string f1 = 1;
>   }
>
>   message M2 {
>     string f1 = 1;
>   }
>
>   oneof value {
>     M1 m1 = 1;
>     M2 m2 = 2;
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want / need, but I need it to be auto-generated.  Creating this by hand will be *a lot* of work.